# Why is my Bitcoin transaction taking so long

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I am new to Bitcoin (using Bitcoin core client) and i tried to make a transaction but its taken 4 days so far and i not sure what to do?

https://blockchain.info/tx/8c2057ca78c0843b881c2620127d140cdeeeb73f38fa6444d9aecd82d0979cc9

Answer (score 0):

The transaction appears to have a very low "fee per byte" of 20.09 satoshis per byte.  A transaction I just completed got confirmed 5 times within 30 minutes or so with a fee per byte of 298 satoshis/byte.

You need to make sure the fee you specify for the transaction is attractive to miners, otherwise it will take a long time for the transaction to be confirmed.

Earn.com has a great bitcoin fee tool at https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/ (I'm not associated with Earn in any way)

Comment: Would there be a way for me to add more money to the fee?